# Smartly omit chapter number in equation numbering

Tags: sectioning, cross-referencing, equations, numbering

In my thesis I use chapters, sections and subsection. I like to have my equations numbered with respect to section, but I want the displayed equations numbers not to include the chapter number. Moreover when referencing the equations I want the chapter number to be excluded unless I reference them from a different chapter.

How can I achieve this? If not otherwise possible it would be ok to use two commands `\ref{}` and `\gref{}` where the first one omits the chapter number. I would like to do the same thing also for references to sections and to theorems. At the moment I am using the koma `scrbook` class.

#### Example

```
I. Chapter 1
1. Section 1
  a^2 + b^2 = c^2         (1.1)
as seen in (1.1)

II. Chapter 2
1. Section 1
an extension of (I.1.1) is
  a^3 + b^3 = c^3         (1.1)
```

Comment: Strongly related: [How do I discard a portion of an equation number when cross-referencing?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8982) (@cmhughes: I've seen math books where they do this or something similar, but I don't recall specifics.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can make the prefix conditional on the current chapter being different to the saved chapter in the reference, something like

```
\documentclass{book}


\renewcommand\theequation{\maybe{\arabic{chapter}}\arabic{section}.\arabic{equation}}
\renewcommand\thechapter{\Roman{chapter}}


\DeclareRobustCommand\maybe[1]{\ifnum#1=\value{chapter}\relax\else\thechapter.\fi}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\chapter{zz}

\section{lll}

\begin{equation}1=0\label{x}\end{equation}

\section{sss}

\begin{equation}1=-1\label{y}\end{equation}

[[[\ref{x}]]]

\chapter{YY}

[[[\ref{x}]]]

\end{document}
```

Comment: This works when my chapters are number arabic. How does this work if I have the chapters number with roman? My `\renewcommand\thechapter{\Roman{chapter}}` messes this up.

Comment: @cideous replace `\maybe{\thechapter}` by `\maybe{\arabic{chapter}}`

Comment: Just add `\renewcommand\thechapter{\Roman{chapter}}` as the second line in your example.

Comment: @cideous Code updated as in comments

Answer (score 2):

I think that there is a slight mistake here. If:

```
\DeclareRobustCommand\maybe[1]{\ifnum#1=\value{chapter}\relax\else\thechapter.\fi}
```

is used, then the current chapter will be displayed, and not the referred chapter.
I propose to use instead:

```
\DeclareRobustCommand\maybe[1]{\ifnum#1=\value{chapter}\relax\else\uppercase\expandafter{\romannumeral#1}.\fi}
```

And it works!