# Equations, tables, figures, sections: reference with chapter number but label without

Tags: cross-referencing

Using the `book` class equations, tables, figures and sections have the chapter number as first number of the label (e.g. the first equation of chapter 2 is equation 2.1).

I want to remove the chapter number from the label but I want to keep it when I refer to it (the best would be keeping it if and only if the reference is outside the chapter where the label is)

Comment: Does http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/102006/15925 help you?  This looks very similar.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I would go:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{refcount}
\usepackage{xstring}

\newcommand\Ref{}
\newcommand\RefNum[1]{%
  \StrBehind{\getrefnumber{#1}}{.}[\Ref]
  \hyperref[#1]{\Ref}}

\newcommand\ChapNum[1]{%
  \StrBefore{\getrefnumber{#1}}{.}[\result]}

\newcommand{\myref}[1]{\ChapNum{#1}%
\ifnum\result=\thechapter \RefNum{#1}\else\ref{#1}\fi}

\begin{document}

\chapter{First}

\begin{figure}
\caption{\label{fig1}Figure chap 1}
\end{figure}

\begin{equation}
x+y=z
\label{eq1}
\end{equation}

\myref{eq1}

\chapter{Second}

\begin{figure}
\caption{\label{fig2}Figure chap 2}
\end{figure}

Here see the Figure \myref{fig1}.

\noindent
Here see the Figure \myref{fig2}.

\noindent
Here for the equation \myref{eq1}
\end{document}
```

The command `\myref` acts as the `\ref` command if you are referring to something in another chapter and suppress the chapter number if you are referring to something in the same chapter.

Comment: `\xspace` does nothing there; its usage is only with parameterless macros.

Comment: @egreg You're right. It remained from a previous attempt to solve the problem. Edited my answer.