# How to enable smart references when using xr-hyper package for producing multi-volume book?

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, zref

I'm using `xr-hyper` package by @David Carlisle and `smartref` package by Giuseppe Bilotta to compile a multi-volume book. `xr-hyper` enables cross-references between different volumes as shows the following code chunk:

```
\newcommand{Volume}{1}% put this is PlasmaBook1.tex 

% This is the code shared by all volumes
\usepackage{xr-hyper}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\ifnum\Volume=1
    \externaldocument{PlasmaBook2}
    \externaldocument{PlasmaBook3}
\else\ifnum\Volume=2
    \externaldocument{PlasmaBook1}
    \externaldocument{PlasmaBook3}
\else\ifnum\Volume=3
    \externaldocument{PlasmaBook1}
    \externaldocument{PlasmaBook2}
\fi\fi\fi
```

And the package `smartref` is used to hide a portion of equation number as explained in [How do I discard a portion of an equation number when cross-referencing?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8982/how-do-i-discard-a-portion-of-an-equation-number-when-cross-referencing)

```
\usepackage{smartref}
\addtoreflist{chapter}
\newcommand*{\srefaux}[1]{%
    \ischapterchanged{#1}% checks if section number has changed
    \ifchapterchanged% if current chapter is different
        \chapterref{#1}.% put the section reference
    \fi% else do nothing
    \ref*{#1}%  <- we changed this to ref*
}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand \theequation {\@arabic\c@equation}
\renewcommand \thefigure   {\@arabic\c@figure}
\renewcommand \thetable    {\@arabic\c@table}
\makeatother

\newcommand*\sref[1]{\hyperref[#1]{\srefaux{#1}}}
\newcommand*\seqref[1]{(\hyperref[#1]{\srefaux{#1}})}
```

Unfortunately, `smartref` mechanism is working only within a single volume. I think this is because `xr-hyper` package reads in only `\newlabel` strings from `aux` files and ignores `\newsmartlabel` tags written by `smartref` as shows the following example borrowed from an actual `aux` file:

```
\newlabel{ch01}{{1}{6}{Общие сведения о плазме}{chapter.4}{}}
\newsmartlabel{ch01}{{1}{1}}
```

So my question is

> how to instruct `xr-hyper` to read both `\newlabel` and
>   `\newsmartlabel` tags?

Perhaps, appropriate code could be included into new version of `xr-hyper` package.

Comment: Have you tried the `zref` suggestion at http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=extref ?

Comment: @AndrewSwann: Unfotyunately, `\zref` seems to not work with hyperref package.