# Smart cross-references between 2 volumes using Zref package

Tags: cross-referencing, zref

Following the post [How to enable smart references when using xr-hyper package for producing multi-volume book?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/151569/how-to-enable-smart-references-when-using-xr-hyper-package-for-producing-multi-v) I tried to elaborate required solution using `zref` package as was suggested by @Andrew Swann. Unfortunatly, I ran into another problem which seems to be a bug in `zref`. So I decided to post the problem description here. I am not sure if is it a proper place for posting such a question but Heiko Oberdiek, the author of `zref` did not answer to my email.

As suggested by @Andrew Swann, I tried to provide cross-references between 2 volumes of a multivolume book using Heiko's package `zref`. I addition, I introduced a property `chaptervalue` in order to provide smart references, which hide a chapter part of an equation number in case when the equation goes from the same chapter where it is referred from. Here is MWE. It contains 3 files.

Common code is saved in `test-zref-common.tex`:

```
% Load packages abd declare external docs.
\usepackage[user,xr]{zref}
\ifnum\Volume=1
    % comment the line below to avoid errors
    \zexternaldocument{test-zref-2}% <============
    \makeatletter
        \zref@ifpropundefined{volume}{
            \zref@newprop{volume}{\Volume}
            \zref@newprop{chaptervalue}{\the\value{chapter}}
        }{}
        \zref@localaddprops{main}{volume,chaptervalue}
    \makeatother
\else
    \zexternaldocument{test-zref-1}
    \makeatletter
        \zref@ifpropundefined{volume}{
            \zref@newprop{volume}{\Volume}
            \zref@newprop{chaptervalue}{\the\value{chapter}}
        }{}
        \zref@localaddprops{main}{volume,chaptervalue}
    \makeatother
\fi

% Reset default equation numbering
\usepackage{amsmath}
\numberwithin{equation}{chapter}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\arabic{equation}}

% Define \sref and \seqref macros for smart cross-references of equations
\makeatletter
\newcommand\ifcurrentchapter[3]{%
  \def\temp@a{\number\value{chapter}}%
  \def\temp@b{\zref@extract{#1}{chaptervalue}}%
  \if\temp@a\temp@b%
    #2%
  \else%
    #3%
  \fi%
}
\newcommand{\sref}[1]{\hbox{\ifcurrentchapter{#1}{}{\zref[chaptervalue]{#1}.}\zref{#1}}}
\newcommand{\seqref}[1]{(\sref{#1})}
\makeatother

% Define a macro to print test text
\newcommand{\testtext}{
    Compare \number\value{chapter} with \zref[chaptervalue]{ch:1}. Equal: \ifcurrentchapter{ch:1}{Yes}{No}
    \par\noindent
    Compare \number\value{chapter} with \zref[chaptervalue]{ch:2}. Equal: \ifcurrentchapter{ch:2}{Yes}{No}
    \par\noindent
    Compare \number\value{chapter} with \zref[chaptervalue]{ch:17}. Equal: \ifcurrentchapter{ch:17}{Yes}{No}
    \par\noindent
    Compare \number\value{chapter} with \zref[chaptervalue]{ch:18}. Equal: \ifcurrentchapter{ch:18}{Yes}{No}
}
```

The common file is read in by Volume 1 (`test-zref-1.tex`)

```
\documentclass[oneside]{book}
\newcommand{\Volume}{1}
\input{test-zref-common}

\begin{document}
\chapter{1 in Volume 1}
\label{ch:1}\zlabel{ch:1}

\testtext

\begin{equation}
  eq1
  \label{1.1}\zlabel{1.1}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
  eq2
  \label{1.2}\zlabel{1.2}
\end{equation}

\seqref{1.1}, \seqref{1.2}; \seqref{2.1}, \seqref{2.2}.
\seqref{17.1}, \seqref{17.2}; \seqref{18.1}, \seqref{18.2}.

\chapter{2  in Volume 2}
\label{ch:2}\zlabel{ch:2}

\testtext

\begin{equation}
  eq3
  \label{2.1}\zlabel{2.1}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
  eq4
  \label{2.2}\zlabel{2.2}
\end{equation}

\seqref{1.1}, \seqref{1.2}; \seqref{2.1}, \seqref{2.2}.
\seqref{17.1}, \seqref{17.2}; \seqref{18.1}, \seqref{18.2}.
\end{document}
```

and by Volume 2 (`test-zref-1.tex`):

```
%\documentclass{scrbook}
\documentclass[oneside]{book}
\newcommand{\Volume}{2}
\setcounter{chapter}{16}
\input{test-zref-common}

\begin{document}

\chapter{1 in Volume 2}
\label{ch:17}\zlabel{ch:17}

\testtext

\begin{equation}
  eq1
  \label{17.1}\zlabel{17.1}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
  eq2
  \label{17.2}\zlabel{17.2}
\end{equation}

\seqref{1.1}, \seqref{1.2}; \seqref{2.1}, \seqref{2.2}.
\seqref{17.1}, \seqref{17.2}; \seqref{18.1}, \seqref{18.2}.

\chapter{2  in Volume 2}
\label{ch:18}\zlabel{ch:18}

\testtext

\begin{equation}
  eq3
  \label{18.1}\zlabel{18.1}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
  eq4
  \label{18.2}\zlabel{18.2}
\end{equation}

\seqref{1.1}, \seqref{1.2}; \seqref{2.1}, \seqref{2.2}.
\seqref{17.1}, \seqref{17.2}; \seqref{18.1}, \seqref{18.2}.
\end{document}
```

It works fine if I refer to Volume #1 from Volume #2 (ie. when the line

```
\zexternaldocument{test-zref-2}
```

is removed from `test-zref-common.tex`). However it fails when I am trying to refer to both volumes, to Volume #1 from Volume #2 and to Volume #2 from Volume #1. `zref` complains that the `chaptervalue` property has been already defined. Attached files demonstrate this problem.

**Is a bug in `zref` or a bug in MWE?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The bugs are in your code, all in the common file.  Firstly, you should define the properties before specifying the external documents.  Secondly, you need to use `\ifnum` not `\if` in your tests.  Here is the revised common file:

```
% Load packages abd declare external docs.
\usepackage[user,xr]{zref}
\makeatletter
\zref@newprop{volume}{\Volume}
\zref@newprop{chaptervalue}{\the\value{chapter}}
\zref@localaddprops{main}{volume,chaptervalue}
\makeatother
\ifnum\Volume=1
    \zexternaldocument{test-zref-2}% <============
\else
    \zexternaldocument{test-zref-1}
\fi

% Reset default equation numbering
\usepackage{amsmath}
\numberwithin{equation}{chapter}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\arabic{equation}}

% Define \sref and \seqref macros for smart cross-references of equations
\makeatletter
\newcommand\ifcurrentchapter[3]{%
  \def\temp@a{\number\value{chapter}}%
  \def\temp@b{\zref@extract{#1}{chaptervalue}}%
  \if\relax\temp@a\else\if\relax\temp@b\else
  \ifnum\temp@a=\temp@b%
    #2%
  \else%
    #3%
  \fi%
  \fi\fi
}
\newcommand{\sref}[1]{\hbox{\ifcurrentchapter{#1}{}{\zref[chaptervalue]{#1}.}\zref{#1}}}
\newcommand{\seqref}[1]{(\sref{#1})}
\makeatother

% Define a macro to print test text
\newcommand{\testtext}{
    Compare \number\value{chapter} with \zref[chaptervalue]{ch:1}. Equal: \ifcurrentchapter{ch:1}{Yes}{No}
    \par\noindent
    Compare \number\value{chapter} with \zref[chaptervalue]{ch:2}. Equal: \ifcurrentchapter{ch:2}{Yes}{No}
    \par\noindent
    Compare \number\value{chapter} with \zref[chaptervalue]{ch:17}. Equal: \ifcurrentchapter{ch:17}{Yes}{No}
    \par\noindent
    Compare \number\value{chapter} with \zref[chaptervalue]{ch:18}. Equal: \ifcurrentchapter{ch:18}{Yes}{No}
}
```

This produces the following page at Chatper 17 in the second document:

[image: Sample output]

Comment: This works but isues an error at first compilation (`! Missing number, treated as zero.`) So it will hardly be impossble to compile a big document if the number of errors exceeds 100. That's why I used `\if\temp@a=\temp@b` instead of `\ifnum\temp@a=\temp@b`. Can you suggest a better solution?

Comment: @IgorKotelnikov Thanks for pointing that out; extra tests now added  before the `\ifnum`.  Note `\if1717` compares `1` with `7`, which is not want you want.  If you are prepared to load `etoolbox`, then you could just write `\ifcurrentchapter` as `\ifdefequal{\value{chapter}}{\zref@extract{#1}{chaptervalue}}{#2}{#3}`

Comment: With this added check (`\if\temp@a\relax\else\if\temp@b\relax\else
  \ifnum\temp@a=\temp@b%`) my XeTeX compiler outputs unexpected Greek capital omega at first run, so I finally choose solution described in 2nd answer.

Comment: @IgorKotelnikov Sorry, should have had `\if\relex\temp@b...` not `\if\temp@b\relax...`.  In any case, there is `\zref@extractdefault` and `\zref@def@extractdefault` one could have used.

Answer (score 3):

Expanding the answer given by @Andrew Swann, I updated his code in the common block to avoid generating errors at the first run of LaTeX over source files when the value of the labels are not known yet. A key point here is that the `chaptervalue` property should be defined with a default value. I take it equal to `-1`. Then, `\ifcurrentchapter` macro could be modified to check if `\temp@b` is negative as it is at the first run. 
In addition, I added `hyperref` and `xr-hyper` packages in order to allow for hyper-references between the volumes of the book.

Here is a final version of `test-zref-common.tex`:

```
% Load packages and declare external docs.
\usepackage{xr-hyper}%                     <== load xr-hyper package
\usepackage[unicode,colorlinks]{hyperref}% <== load hyperref package
\usepackage[user,xr]{zref}
\makeatletter
\zref@newprop{volume}{\Volume}
\zref@newprop{chaptervalue}[-1]{\the\value{chapter}}% <= note the default value [-1]
\zref@localaddprops{main}{volume,chaptervalue}
\makeatother
\ifnum\Volume=1
    \externaldocument{test-zref-2}%  <== declare external doc for xr-hyper
    \zexternaldocument{test-zref-2}% <== declare external doc for zref
\else
    \externaldocument{test-zref-1}
    \zexternaldocument{test-zref-1}
\fi

% Reset default equation numbering
\usepackage{amsmath}
\numberwithin{equation}{chapter}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\arabic{equation}}

% Define \sref and \seqref macros for smart cross-references of equations
\makeatletter
\newcommand\ifcurrentchapter[3]{%
  \def\temp@a{\number\value{chapter}}%
  \def\temp@b{\zref@extract{#1}{chaptervalue}}%
  \ifnum\temp@a=\temp@b%
    #2%
  \else%
    \ifnum\temp@b<0
      #2%
    \else
      #3%
    \fi%
  \fi%
}
%\newcommand{\sref}[1]{\hbox{\ifcurrentchapter{#1}{}{\zref[chaptervalue]{#1}.}\zref{#1}}}
% note \hyperref in the definition of \sref
\newcommand{\sref}[1]{\hyperref[#1]{\hbox{\ifcurrentchapter{#1}{}{\zref[chaptervalue]{#1}.}\zref{#1}}}}
\newcommand{\seqref}[1]{(\sref{#1})}
%\newcommand{\seqref}[1]{(\hyperref[#1]{\hbox{\sref{#1}}})}
\makeatother

% Define a macro to print test text
\newcommand{\testtext}{
    Chapter \sref{ch:1}, Chapter \sref{ch:2},
    Chapter \sref{ch:17}, Chapter \sref{ch:18}.
    \par\noindent
    Compare \number\value{chapter} with \zref[chaptervalue]{ch:1}. Equal: \ifcurrentchapter{ch:1}{Yes}{No}
    \par\noindent
    Compare \number\value{chapter} with \zref[chaptervalue]{ch:2}. Equal: \ifcurrentchapter{ch:2}{Yes}{No}
    \par\noindent
    Compare \number\value{chapter} with \zref[chaptervalue]{ch:17}. Equal: \ifcurrentchapter{ch:17}{Yes}{No}
    \par\noindent
    Compare \number\value{chapter} with \zref[chaptervalue]{ch:18}. Equal: \ifcurrentchapter{ch:18}{Yes}{No}
    \par
    \seqref{1.1}, \seqref{1.2}; \seqref{2.1}, \seqref{2.2}.
    \par
    \seqref{17.1}, \seqref{17.2}; \seqref{18.1}, \seqref{18.2}.
}

\endinput
```