# \hyperref fails when cross-referencing between different files

Tags: errors, hyperref, cross-referencing, miktex, xr

I am working on a multi-volume project where different volumes contain hyperlinks to other volumes. I use a technique described on this web-site in a number of posts, see e.g., [Cross-referencing between different files](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14364/cross-referencing-between-different-files)  and  [Smart cross-references between 2 volumes using Zref package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/152502/smart-cross-references-between-2-volumes-using-zref-package) .

I remember that it worked fine in the past but recently I noted that a hyperlink to another file opens it on a last opened page rather than on a desired destination page. Here are not so small working examples which I made to test this problem.  I compile these files to pdf with pdflatex or xetex.

File A.tex:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[user,xr]{zref}
%\usepackage{zref-xr}
\usepackage{xr-hyper}
\externaldocument[B-]{B}
\zexternaldocument[B-]{B}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}

empty page

\newpage
\section{Dittmer}\label{Dittmer}\zlabel{Dittmer}

Dittmer

\newpage
\section{Langmuir}\label{Langmuir}\zlabel{Langmuir}

Langmuir

\newpage
\section{References}

\hyperref[Dittmer]{hyperref to Dittmer} on page \pageref{Dittmer}, \zpageref{Dittmer}

\hyperref[Langmuir]{hyperref to Langmuir} on page \pageref{Langmuir}, \zpageref{Langmuir}

\hyperref[B-Shafranov]{hyperref to B-Shafranov} on page \pageref{B-Shafranov}, \zpageref{B-Shafranov}

\hyperref[B-Stupakov]{hyperref to B-Stupakov} on page \pageref{B-Stupakov}, \zpageref{B-Stupakov}

\end{document}
```

File B.tex:

```
%\providecommand{\reverseit}[1]{#1}
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[user,xr]{zref}
%\usepackage{zref-xr}
\usepackage{xr-hyper}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\externaldocument[A-]{A}
\zexternaldocument[A-]{A}
%\externaldocument[V4-]{PlasmaBook4}

\begin{document}

empty page 

\newpage
\section{Shafranov}\label{Shafranov}\zlabel{Shafranov}

Shafranov

\newpage
\section{Stupakov}\label{Stupakov}\zlabel{Stupakov}

Stupakov

\newpage
\section{References}

\hyperref[A-Dittmer]{hyperref to A-Dittmer} on page \pageref{A-Dittmer}, \zpageref{A-Dittmer}

\hyperref[A-Langmuir]{hyperref to A-Langmuir} on page \pageref{A-Langmuir}, \zpageref{A-Langmuir}

\hyperref[Shafranov]{hyperref to Shafranov} on page \pageref{Shafranov}, \zpageref{Shafranov}

\hyperref[Stupakov]{hyperref to Stupakov} on page \pageref{Stupakov}, \zpageref{Stupakov}

\end{document}
```

I have no idea what became broken in this technique. Any advice would be most appreciated. `\refpage`, `\zrefpage` print correct page numbers in different files but hyperlinks by  `\refpage` and `\hyperref` open different file of a wrong page. I tried sumatrapdf and adobe accrobat to browse pdf files.

**UPDATE:** Finally, I found that `\hyperref` does not operate as desired on external document if PDFs were compiled under `MiKTeX` (either by `xelatex` or `pdflatex`). When compiled by `TeX Live` everything works as intended! So this seems to be bug in `MiKTeX`.

**UPDATE 2017-02-13**: Today I've checked that the above described problem is absent with the most recent versions of MikTex and TeXlive.

Answer (score 5):

`A.tex`: Package `xr-hyper` needs to be loaded before `hyperref` but `\externaldocument` should be given *after* loading `hyperref`:

```
\usepackage{xr-hyper}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\externaldocument[B-]{B}
```

Comment: What about `zref`  and `\zexternaldocument`?

Comment: @IgorKotelnikov With the change from the answer, all links in the references sections work for me as expected.

Comment: but it doesn't work for me! I sent you files compiled on my computer. Is it work as desired on your computer?

Comment: I found that `\hyperref` does not operate as desired on external document if PDF were compiled under MiKTeX (either by xelatex or pdflatex). When compiled by TeX Live everything works as intended!

Comment: @IgorKotelnikov: I can not confirm your claim. If I move the (z)externaldocument commands behind hyperref and compile often enough with miktex the links works fine. I tested in sumatra 3.0 and acrobat reader DC.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Iv'e checked this problem twice on two my computers.

Comment: @IgorKotelnikov: I don't doubt that you have a problem. But I can't make a bug report if I can't reproduce it or understand the cause. Make zip-folder with the a + b.tex and all the compilation files so that one compare the files. Which pdf-viewer are you using? Which OS?