# How to make the enumeration of theorem-like environments indipendent from cross-referencing in a particular way

Tags: cross-referencing, chapters, theorems, labels, automation

I'm writing a mathematical paper, and right now I'm using

```
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
```

to enumerate theorems, propositions, etc. In this way, every statement shows the number of the chapter, the number of the section and then the number of the statement in that section.

This is quite standard, but I would like to do it something differently: I'd like to omit the chapter number when stating the propositions, but show it every time I'm referring to that proposition outside the chapter.

I've already seen it in some books, is there an easy way to do it?

Comment: related, though probably not duplicate: [How do I discard a portion of an equation number when cross-referencing?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8982/579)

Answer (score 7):

Here is what you want

Theorem's label

```
\renewcommand{\thetheorem}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{theorem}}
```

LaTex uses a prefix `\p@counter` for cross-referencing i.e. a reference to a theorem produce `\p@theorem\thetheorem`

in this case `\p@theorem= null` inside chapter and `\p@theorem=chapter number` outside.

```
\p@theorem=\ifnum\thechapter=chapter of theorem\else\thechapter.\fi
```

we do this with

```
\renewcommand{\p@theorem}{\string\ifnum\string\thechapter=\thechapter\string\else\thechapter.\string\fi}
```

Note: `\string` for aux writing without expantion

```
\documentclass{book}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\renewcommand{\thetheorem}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{theorem}}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\p@theorem}{\string\ifnum\string\thechapter=\thechapter\string\else\thechapter.\string\fi}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\chapter{Foo}
bla bla bla
\section{Bar}
\begin{theorem}\label{th:first}
test
\end{theorem}
\ref{th:first}
\begin{theorem}\label{th:second}
test
\end{theorem}
\begin{theorem}\label{th:last}
test
\end{theorem}

\chapter{BAR}
bla bla bla
\section{Baz}
\begin{theorem}
test
\end{theorem}
\ref{th:first}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What's particularly nifty about your solution is that it works seamlessly with the `hyperref` and `cleveref` packages.

Comment: Is there a way to modify your solution so that it can handle lettered (A, B, C...) as well as numbered (1, 2, 3...) chapter "numbers"?

Comment: @Mico we can do `\renewcommand{\p@theorem}{\string\if\string\thechapter\string\detokenize{\thechapter}\string\relax\protect\else\thechapter.\protect\fi}`. I will edit my answer

Comment: @Mico this will fail if chapter number >9. I will try,  but i think this will drive me to egreg's method.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer, and for looking into how your approach might be extended to handle chapter "numbers" that don't use arabic numbers but, say, alphabetic letters or Roman numerals.

Answer (score 5):

Extending touhami's idea, but making it work also for nonstandard chapter numbers (like for theorems in an appendix), I make `\p@theorem` expand to `\compare@theorem{\thetheorem}`, where `\compare@theorem` is a protected macro; thus only `\thetheorem` is expanded when writing to the `.aux` file. The macro `\compare@theorem` uses `\pdfstrcmp` (under the abstraction `\pdf@strcmp` provided by `pdftexcmds` so the code works also with XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX): with it the comparison is between strings, not numeric.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{pdftexcmds}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]

\renewcommand{\thetheorem}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{theorem}}

\makeatletter
\protected\def\compare@theorem#1{%
  \ifnum\pdf@strcmp{#1}{\thechapter}=\z@
  \else
    #1.%
  \fi
}
\renewcommand{\p@theorem}{\compare@theorem{\thechapter}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\chapter{Foo}
bla bla bla
\section{Bar}
\begin{theorem}\label{th:first}
test
\end{theorem}
\ref{th:first}
\begin{theorem}\label{th:second}
test
\end{theorem}
\begin{theorem}\label{th:last}
test
\end{theorem}

\chapter{BAR}
bla bla bla
\section{Baz}
\begin{theorem}
test
\end{theorem}
\ref{th:first}

\ref{th:app}

\appendix

\chapter{APP}

\section{Aps}

\begin{theorem}\label{th:app}
test
\end{theorem}

\ref{th:app}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Many thanks for this answer, which can handle several enumeration styles (e.g., arabic, alphabetic, and Roman numerals) and works seemlessly with cross-referencing packages such as `hyperref` and `cleveref` (and a few more as well, I guess).

Answer (score 3):

The following solution weighs way more than the rather clever approach of @touhami; in exchange you gain more flexibility regarding changes to the theorem interface.

How to use it: After defining a new theorem environment using `\newtheorem` you can use the new command `\theoremnum` to specify a numbering that is indipendent from the reference mechanism. (The additional property that references within the same chapter should display the same numbering as the theorems they refer to is covered.) In your case you would declare:

```
\theoremnum{theorem}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{theorem}}
```

after `\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]` to get rid of the chapter number.

[image: output_part-1]

[image: output_part-2]

[image: output_part-3]

#### Complete code

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{xstring}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\theoremnum}[2]{%
  \expandafter\let\csname the#1@\expandafter\endcsname\csname the#1\endcsname
  \expandafter\def\csname the#1\endcsname{#2}
  \expandafter\def\csname label@#1\endcsname##1{%
    \@bsphack
    \protected@write\@auxout{}%
      {\string\newlabel{##1}{{\csname the#1\endcsname}{\thepage}}}%
    \protected@write\@auxout{}%
      {\string\newlabel{##1@full}{{\csname the#1@\endcsname}{\thepage}}}%
    \@esphack%
  }
  \expandafter\g@addto@macro\csname #1\endcsname{%
    \expandafter\let\csname label\expandafter\endcsname\csname label@#1\endcsname%
  }
}
\let\orig@ref\ref
\renewcommand{\ref}[1]{%
  \NumBefore{\orig@ref{#1@full}}[\@refchapter]%
  \ifnum\thechapter=\@refchapter\relax
    \orig@ref{#1}
  \else
    \orig@ref{#1@full}
  \fi%
}
\def\NumBefore#1{%
  \kernel@ifnextchar[{\NumBefore@{#1}}{\NumBefore@{#1}[]}%
}
\def\NumBefore@#1[#2]{%
  \begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup\noexpand\find@sep#1.\relax}\x
  \StrBefore{#1}{\@sep}[#2]%
}
\def\find@sep#1#2\relax{%
  \if<\ifnum9<1#1<\else>\fi
    \expandafter\find@sep#2.\relax%
  \else
    \def\@sep{#1}%
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\theoremnum{theorem}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{theorem}}

\begin{document}
\chapter{baz}
\section{zzzzz}

\noindent Reference to \verb|thm:test| \emph{outside} of chapter `foo': \ref{thm:test}

\chapter{foo}
\section{zzz}

\begin{theorem}
  \label{thm:test}
  Test theorem.
\end{theorem}

\noindent Reference to \verb|thm:test| \emph{inside} of chapter `foo': \ref{thm:test}

\chapter{bar}
\section{zzzz}

\noindent Reference to \verb|thm:test| \emph{outside} of chapter `foo': \ref{thm:test}
\end{document}
```

*Note*: The way this solution uses redefinitions of the cross-referencing mechanism it won't be usable with `heyperref`. If that is a criterion you better go with the other solution.